# Trying to import script in RUTA, getting an error that script is not found

Tags: eclipse, uima, ruta

I have a project which is defined in eclipse as both a java/UIMA project and a RUTA project. The path to my scripts is MyProject/script/myPackage, and it currently contains two script files. I'm trying to import one of them into the other, using

```
SCRIPT myPackage.FirstScript;
```

but I get the error:

> error: "myPackage.FirstScript" not found.

If I simply erase that and write "SCRIPT" in a newline and use Eclipse autocompletion, Eclipse supplies the script name as above, but the error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of UIMA Ruta Workbench do you use? Is the error reported in the problems view, or logged in the console? Have you tried to rebuild all descriptors?

Comment: @PeterKluegl, I'm using the 2.1.0 version of the Ruta Workbench. The error appears in the problems view (Type: DLTK Problem). How do I rebuild the descriptors? I've tried cleaning and building the project several times. Also, the descriptor for the second script engine references the first both in the additionalScripts parameter and as an imported Type System, and the scriptPaths parameter points to the same package in which both scripts appear.

Comment: The scriptPath should point to the script folder of the project, and the additionalScripts should contain the package of the script, e.g., additionalScripts has to contain myPackage.FirstScript. Are there any cyclic dependencies? Have you tried to run the script? Maybe it's just a small bug in the validator of the editor.

Comment: Rebuilding the descriptors is performed exactly with your approach. You can also delete the folders in the descriptor folder and then modify the script file and save it. The building of script files is quite similar to the java approach, but missed yet the correct order of the dependencies.